# Сортировка с заданным параметром MySql

Tags: php, mysql

Добрый день! Есть такой запрос

```
SELECT distinct p.id, p.articul, p.price, p.count, p.title
FROM tm_product p
INNER JOIN tm_gallery ph ON p.id = ph.id_product
WHERE p.id_subcategory = $id_subcategory
ORDER BY p.id DESC
```

Который показывает все товары, по заданной категории, у которых есть изображение.

Есть второй запрос

```
SELECT distinct p.id, p.articul, p.price, p.count, p.title
FROM tm_product p
LEFT JOIN tm_gallery ph ON p.id = ph.id_product
WHERE p.id_subcategory = $id_subcategory and ph.id is null
ORDER BY p.id DESC
```

Аналогично только показывает у которых нету изорбражения.

А какой запрос можно написать что бы показать все товары но с сортировкой, сначала те которые с изображением, а потом у которых нету фото.

```
SELECT distinct p.id, p.articul, p.price, p.count, p.title
FROM tm_product p
WHERE p.id_subcategory = $id_subcategory 
ORDER BY ???
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

используйте [`CASE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/control-flow-functions.html#operator_case) для сортировки и `LEFT JOIN`для связывания таблиц.

```
SELECT distinct p.id, p.articul, p.price, p.count, p.title
FROM tm_product p
LEFT JOIN tm_gallery ph ON p.id = ph.id_product
WHERE p.id_subcategory = ?

ORDER BY 
    CASE WHEN ph.id IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END
  , p.id DESC
```

Comment: не пропущено END CASE?

Comment: @Jean-Claude не пропущено, ссылка была неправильная, если вы там прочитали

Comment: @teran, уже не первый раз замечаю, поэтому всё-таки спрошу. А почему люди используют именно CASE? Здесь же всего два варианта, почему не IF? CASE быстрее работает? или приятнее читать? P.S. никакого сарказма, мне реально интересно.

Comment: @АлександрБелинский наверное, потому что ее в стандарте нет? а case он везде